# "Non-ASCII character" error when running Python program from Windows Powershell

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I am seeing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x93' in file new2.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

when I run this code:

```
print(“Welcome")
 guess = 0
 while guess != 5:
    g = input(“Guess the number: ")
    guess = int(g)
    if guess == 5:
    print(“You win!")
    else:
    if guess > 5:
    print(“Too high")
    else:
    print(“Too low")
print(“Game over!")
```

Comment: What symbol is `“` supposed to be? On the line `g = input(“Guess the number: ")` - same in your `print` statements

Comment: Your endquote is correct `"` but your opening quotes are both *smart quotes*, which aren't ascii. Did you copy & paste this from some other application, that may be the cause of your errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use proper double quotes, not the `“` sign, which is not ASCII.

Comment: It's mentioned in comments but these are also known as "smart quotes". Almost always the problem created by code biting from a website.